# When Rounding to nearest hundreds, how do I include 0s

Tags: python, python-3.x, numbers, rounding

So let's say I have this code:

```
num = 1.29283
round(num, 2)
```

That rounds to 1.29, but if I do this:

```
num = 1.30293
round(num, 2)
```

That rounds to 1.3. I want to know if there is a way to have it round to 1.30; I know it is the same number, but I need it to print 1.30.

Comment: `1.3` and `1.30` are the *same* number. If you care about the *representation* of the output, then you're after a string, not a number: look into string formatting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use string formatting for this. A number in python does not have such a thing as trailing zeros. So your question only make sense for strings.

Example:

```
>>> num = 1.30293
>>> "{:.2f}".format(num)
'1.30'
```

The `.2f` says that this is a float (`f`) and that you want two digits after the point `.2`. Read more about string formatting [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-examples)